# any method in xamarin forms equivalent to shouldOverride method of android

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

Is there any method in xamarin forms equivalent to shouldOverrideUrlLoading method of android. That will let me handle a JS callback. Please note I'm trying on non native. So please don't suggest solutions native to android or iOS.

Comment: No there is not, you will have to use a custom renderer.

Comment: @GeraldVersluis can you please suggest me how to implement the same using a custom renderer?

Comment: A lot more information is required on what you are trying to achieve. And honestly, I could give you a full solution, but I think you'll learn more if you dig some yourself. Also because Stack Overflow is not a platform for providing coding-as-a-services. We expect a bit more input. What have you tried? Where did you fail? What code is associated and do you get any error messages? I suggest you look into creating custom renderers and bridging to platform specific code. If you run into any problems we will be happy to help.

Comment: @GeraldVersluis I have a JS function inside html which populates the data in webview. I want to access the url in c# code. The below is the js call inside html which should invoke my c# code based on callback provided but its not happening.  window.location = "js-call:" + "1" + ":" + encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify({query:jsonTimeDetails , type:'sendTimeDetails', callback:'saveContentInfo'}));

Comment: ok I figured out how i can do it alternatively. Browser.Navigating += OnNavigatedHandler; allows you to catch the URL and args.Cancel = true; cancels the navigation